# How to write multiple foreach condition in a single line

Tags: php, mysql

my code is not working it's showing error in condition.

```
 <?
 foreach($_POST['check'] as $value )   
 foreach($_POST['emp'] as $value2 )     
 { 
 mysql_query("insert into tb_recived_jobs set job_id='$value'emp_id='$value2'");  
 }     
 ?>
```

Comment: [`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will soon be removed. Please use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20767765/1612146)

Comment: is $_POST['check'] is an array?

Comment: You should consider building one large query with string concatination. An extra query for every row is very unperformant and can make your page/script very slow.

Comment: Nested foreach creates a cross-product. I don't think that's what you really want. The error you're getting has nothing to do with `foreach`, it's probably because you left out the `,` between the variables in the SQL.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: It's always a good idea to wrap the bodies of your `foreach` with `{}`, even if it's one line.

Answer (score 1):

You should use For loop to do this

```
$count = count($_POST['check']);

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++) {
    $value= $_POST['check'][$i];
    $value2= $_POST['emp'][$i];
    mysql_query("insert into tb_recived_jobs(job_id,emp_id) values('$value','$value2')"); 
}
```

Comment: All I expected you to do was add a comma, not switch to the other syntax! But OK.

Answer (score 1):

correct your SQL Query like this :

```
"insert into tb_recived_jobs set job_id='$value' emp_id='$value2'"
```

you are missing one space between first value and second column,
make an INSERT SQL query like this one helps much more:

```
"INSERT INTO `tb_recived_jobs` (`job_id`, `emp_id`) VALUES ('$value', '$value2');"
```

---

UPDATE:
I just realized what is wrong exactly, cause here you have two arrays and you want to insert their values by a query, in this case both arrays should have same length to everything goes well

```
$checks = $_POST['check'];
$emps = $_POST['emp'];

$length = count($checks);
if ($length === count($emps)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tb_received_jobs` (`job_id`, `emp_id`) VALUES ('{$checks[$i]}', '{$emps[$i]}');";
        //  send the query
    }
}
```

this should work properly.

Comment: Space isn't required, but comma is.

Answer (score 0):

You can **merge** two array $_POST['check'] and $_POST['emp'] in one array after than you can use foreach for this.

Comment: What merging function do you suggest? `array_merge()` isn't correct for this.

Comment: Yes array_merge is not correct need to make custom function. it will makes according array

Answer (score 0):

try this as i understand if you want to insert each `$_POST['emp']` for every `$_POST['check']`

```
<?
foreach($_POST['check'] as $value ) 
{  
 foreach($_POST['emp'] as $value2 )     
 { 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tb_recived_jobs`(job_id, emp_id) VALUES('$value', '$value2')") or die(mysql_error());  
 } 
}    
 ?>
```